# Use \GlsXtrSetAltModifier to typeset glossaries link text?

Tags: glossaries, glossaries-extra

I want to emphasize use of certain terms in the glossary, and when doing so I also want to emphasize the page number in the index.

From an earlier [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/254699/2634), I found that I can use the `format` option to customize the font of the page number. Together with the `\GlsXtrSetAltModifier` command from the `glossaries-extra` package, I managed to achieve the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}
\makeglossaries

\newcommand{\emphPageNumber}[1]{{\itshape\glshypernumber{#1}}}
\GlsXtrSetAltModifier{!}{format=emphPageNumber}

\newglossaryentry{term}{name={term}, description=\nopostdesc}

\begin{document}
Emphasized use of \gls!{term}, normal use of \gls{term}.

\printglossary{}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I still need to manually modify the style of the entry itself (e.g. `\emph{\gls!{term}}`. Is there any easy way of achieving that simply using `\gls!` does that for me automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of the `\glslinkpostsetkeys` hook, which is called after the keys (provided in the first optional argument of `\gls`, `\glslink` etc) are set. The `format` key sets the definition of `\@glsnumberformat` to the supplied format, so `\glslinkpostsetkeys` can be redefined to check that command. Since it's an internal command, it needs `\makeatletter` / `\makeatother` if the code is added to the `.tex` file (rather than a class or package).

The `etoolbox` command `\ifdefstring` can be used to check if `\@glsnumberformat` is `emphPageNumber`. The entry text is formatted according to `\glstextformat`, which by default just does its argument, but it can be changed here to use the appropriate formatting command:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}
\makeglossaries

\newcommand{\emphPageNumber}[1]{{\itshape\glshypernumber{#1}}}
\GlsXtrSetAltModifier{!}{format=emphPageNumber}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\glslinkpostsetkeys}{%
 \ifdefstring\@glsnumberformat{emphPageNumber}%
 {\let\glstextformat\textit}%
 {\let\glstextformat\@firstofone}%
}
\makeatother

\newglossaryentry{term}{name={term}, description=\nopostdesc}

\begin{document}
Emphasized use of \gls!{term}, normal use of \gls{term}.

\printglossary

\end{document}
```

Incidentally, `\hyperit` provided by the `glossaries` package does pretty much the same thing as your custom `\emphPageNumber`.

Using the `makeglossaries` Perl script in the build process, the above MWE produces:

[image: Image of document. Location list only contains emphasized 1]

Calling `makeindex` directly or using the `makeglossaries-lite` Lua script or the `automake` package option instead produces:

[image: Image of document. Location list contains emphasized 1 and upright 1]

(The `makeglossaries` Perl script detects `makeindex`'s "multiple encaps for the same page under same key" warning and tries to correct the problem.)

If `hyperref` isn't used, then there's a simpler method if you always want the text format to reflect the location format:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}
\makeglossaries

\newcommand{\emphPageNumber}[1]{{\itshape\glshypernumber{#1}}}
\GlsXtrSetAltModifier{!}{format=emphPageNumber}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\glstextformat}{\csname \@glsnumberformat\endcsname}
\makeatother

\newglossaryentry{term}{name={term}, description=\nopostdesc}

\begin{document}
Emphasized use of \gls!{term}, normal use of \gls{term}.
Bold use \gls[format=hyperbf]{term}

\printglossary

\end{document}
```

This can't be used with `hyperref` as it will try to form a hyperlink from the text with `\glshypernumber`, which expects a location as the argument.